# Rest Web API shows records in localserver, but not in IIS

Tags: iis, webapi, rest

I am trying to use Rest web API , to retrieve data.
When i am building and executing it using localserver, it is displaying the data.
But, when i publish it and use IIS to access it does not show any data. and shows this

**"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."**

i am already using the same API for the functions of fileupload and they are working. Its just the matter of database, whenever i have to access database,it showing me the error above(This error means that no data is fetched).

Can you please help me with it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common reason behind the issue is iis user does not have enough permission to access the database.

To resolve the issue you can assign the database domain user which has enigh access to the database to the application pool by following below steps:

1)Open iis manager

2)select your application pool -> advanced setting.

3)Under Process Model, click on the “Identity” value and select “Custom account”.

[image]

enter your domain user name(DOMAIN\USERNAME) and password which user has to access to the database and click ok to apply the changes.

after applying changes select the application pool and click on the “Recycle”.

If you still face an issue you could refer below link for how to configure application pool user in SQL server.

https://forums.iis.net/post/2159167.aspx

Comment: Hi Jalpa,Thanks a lot for the link.  I added the pool to database and it started working. I didint have to change the identity